# Doctrine migrations: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement

Tags: php, postgresql, doctrine, database-migration, doctrine-migrations

I am trying to prepare first migration for project, that has quite big postgres database. I have dumped production DB schema, cleared it from comments and empty lines, and put whole as a text in single variable. Then I called

```
$this->addSql($sql);
```

When I tried to run this migration, i have been punched in the face with

> SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  cannot insert multiple
>   commands into a prepared statement

Do I really need to split every SQL command into separate call of addSql method? There are few thousands of lines of SQLs in the cleared dump. It will be painful to do it by hand and I am not willing to do that with scripting, because something could go wrong and I wouldn't even notice it.

Comment: did you fixed this problem? how did you fixed it?@Fisher

Comment: Do you already have the doctrine mapping for the complete database?